# How can i achieve the specific directory of a file in Python?

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

So I'm a novice to Python, and as predicted, I've run into an issue when trying to figure out a file's directory. In my IDE, when I run the code:

```
Import OS
print(os.path.abspath("background.png"))
```

It works fine. (Bear in mind, the picture is in the same directory as the Python code. I'm also aware that you can use the following:

```
print(os.path.abspath(r"OldBGs\background.png"))
```

This returns:

C:\Users\me\Desktop...few folders...\OldBGs\background.png

This is what I am currently working with. However, when I try to run my code without my IDE (I do this by right-clicking the code.py and then choosing open with Python 3.8), for some reason it outputs:

C:\WINDOWS\system32\OldBGs\backgroundold.png

This is a pain, although it works with my IDE, I need to ensure that it works no matter whoever runs my code (with/without an IDE).

Comment: I have removed your second question (or _"side"_), because an SO question should be just one question, otherwise it would be correct to close the question altogether.

Comment: @KosayJabre's answer gives a good way to deal with this problem.  It doesn't explain WHY what you're doing doesn't work.  The reason for that is that `abspath` uses the "current directory" as the starting point for relative paths, and that location is not guaranteed to be the directory of the script being run. Unless you're writing a command line tool, it's usually best to avoid relying on the value of the current directory.  The provided solution is a good way to go about this.

Comment: Thank you @Steve and zvone and Vincent. I appreciate the help, I'm also new to stack overflow but as I have just learnt, this forum page is amazing for aspiring programmers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to make all paths relative to the *position of the script file itself*.

You can get the path to the directory of the script by:

```
import os
SCRIPT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then, you can define all paths relative to `SCRIPT_DIRECTORY` . For example:

```
BACKGROUND_PICTURE_PATH = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIRECTORY , "background.png")
```

This path is now no longer dependent on where the script was run from, but where the script file itself is located. This means it will be the same path whether or not you're in an IDE.

Answer (score -1):

In python, you can change your directory using the command `os.chdir(your_path)`.

Then you can add to your script:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

If you want to open the file you can now use:

```
file = open("background.png")
```

Then you start at your file.py. If your file "background.png" is in the same directory you can acces to the path using:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "background.png")
```

Then if you want to go back through directories use:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "..", "background.png")
```

In some IDE you can add some bash lines on a execution. Simply add the command `cd SCRIPT_PATH` (Variable of SCRIPT_PATH is IDE dependant)

Comment: I don't see that calling `chdir` has any value at all here.  All of the subsequent operations make use of the absolute directory of \_\_file__.  The current directory is never used here, so why set it?  Other than setting the cwd, your answer is a duplicate of the first one posted.

Comment: Calling ``chdir`` could be usefull for other operation like open the file. After this use ``open("background.png")``

Comment: But your answer doesn't say that, and that has nothing to do with answering the question.  It's not only useless to mention it the way you do...it's quite misleading.

Comment: The question start with "I'm a novice to Python", I am just helping this person to understand how it works. There is no fixed question here, he just try to understand I think. With the variables name, I think he is not just going to print the path but use the file. Try to understand the need before downvote

Comment: If my downvote and response were not appropriate, why did you respond to them by changing your answer to address what I said?  That is fairly strong confirmation that you agreed with me.  I would remove my downvote except for the fact that I see other problems with your answer, and feel that it is too much a duplicate of an answer that already existed.  You'd have been better of sticking to just your first solution instead of complicating things by offering two distinct solutions, especially when your wording does not make it clear that the second solution doesn't somehow rely on the first.